# WordPress - changing CSS style

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using *WordPress*, looking forwards to changing CSS style sheet.

I cannot see as explained in http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/ any ability for editing **'CSS'** (no any option for  Appearance → Customize → **'CSS'**).

What I do: Site admin -> Appearance -> Customize.

My **WordPress** version is WordPress 4.0.

Comment: You've linked to documentation on WordPress.com which is only for _their hosted product_.  That's entirely different than you having WordPress installed on your own server ([that's WordPress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page)).  Which one you have is not entirely clear by your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each theme has some files. One of the files can be css - theme is located in `wp-content/themes/nameoftheme` directory. 
Use `Appearance -> Editor`.

Search for file with css extension - appending to this file will affect changes to css in your theme.

Make changes and click save.

Note!
If in css theme in your editor you refresh page and changes don't save, then You should give write permissions to this **css theme file** on server.